# How blender got its name?

Tags: interface

Like the title,how blender got its name.I just want to know why [Ton Roosendaal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ton_Roosendaal) call it Blender.Is it from the blender machine or something like that?

Any help was very appreciated.

Comment: Maybe ask him? This is opinions otherwise.

Comment: Since we are on the subject of it being a name - names are capitalized. It is not blender that we use to make 3d, it is Blender. I am really surprised to see so many people making mistakes like that. It looks very unprofessional and always makes me think that if a person makes mistakes like this I should probably expect them to make other mistakes in general as well so I tend not to trust and question what they say and do. I fail to see why anyone would want to be perceived like that.

Comment: While not opinion based (there actually is a written history about it) I still don't think it is a suitable question for this site since it is not about using the software

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about using Blender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender got its name from a song used in [NeoGeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CdA_NMw7lc)'s showreel, the company that started developing Blender.

The song's name is [Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaZTSDfT1o4) by [Yello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yello), a Swiss electronic music band, as stated at the [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_(software)).

[image]